# Determine $\phi(2^{399}+1)$

Tags: number-theory

This is a question I had on an exam so there is no access to calculators or software. I checked the answer using Maple after and as expected, the answer is very large and some of the prime factors are also very large, with over 10 digits.

Is there any reasonable way to break this down and get an answer of some sort?

Comment: Does $\phi$ denote the Euler totient?

Comment: Maybe the exam asked to find its congruence class? Was it all? Seems like a silly question to ask.

Comment: Yes, that's the Euler totient function.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, I have a feeling that your professor must have meant something else. I don't see how this can be answered in any reasonable way.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. As this was asked as an exam question it should be something relatively easy to figure out but no one answered it and no one here is having any luck. If I get some answer in class on Monday I'll post it here.

Comment: Here's my guess: the question was supposed to be $\mu(2^{399}+1)$.  This is zero, as this number is not squarefree (it is relatively easy to show that 9 divides it).

Comment: Intended answer: some very large number.

Comment: easy way to show $9$ divides it:
$$
(2^{399} + 1) \equiv ((2^3)^{133} + 1) 
\equiv ((-1)^{133} + 1) \pmod 9 
$$

Comment: Update on this problem?

Comment: Got feedback on this today in class. I'm not sure if it was a mistake or not but the prof said he basically wanted us to see that these are hard things to compute and that's why they're used in cryptography. So, no real answer. I feel safe saying the only way to do it is computationally with software like Maple

Comment: @Mango Thanks, that's what I thought! Seems like a harsh lesson to put that on an exam though...

Comment: @Mango I suggest you write that as an answer and accept it, so that this question is removed from the unanswered list.

Comment: My crystal ball [works](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022120/determine-phi23991#comment2085582_1022120)!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After getting feedback on this question in class, it appears that there is no feasible way to do this by hand and it can be easily computed using software such as Maple.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $399 = 3 \times 7 \times 19$.  Letting $x = 2^{21}$, we have
$$
2^{21\times 19} + 1 = x^{19} + 1= (x + 1)(x^{18}-x^{17} + \cdots -x + 1)
$$
Letting $z = 2^7$, we have
$$
x+1 = z^3 + 1 = (z+1)(z^2 - z + 1)
$$
So far, we have
$$
2^{399}+1 = (x^{18}-x^{17} + \cdots -x + 1) \times129 \times 16257
$$
which is a very slight improvement.

Comment: But it's not enough to just break $2^{399}+1$ into factors, the factors must be relatively prime for this to be of any use.  Do you propose factoring $2^{399}+1$ into primes?

Comment: @vadim123 my idea was to break it up into primes, eventually.  But perhaps your idea is better.

Comment: I don't have any ideas, but I'm pretty sure that factoring $2^{399}+1$ into primes is hopeless by hand.

Comment: You should of course pull out the $3$s from $129$ and $16257$.

Comment: This is similar to how me and some others were trying to solve the problem. I don't think there's any way to do this by hand as some of the factors are just too large. Perhaps it was just a mistake by my professor but he also gave us an extension to find the answer.