# How can I find the answer to $\varphi(2^{400} + 2)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I find the answer to $\varphi(2^{400} + 2)$ ?

So far I have
$\varphi(2^{400}) = 2^{400} - 2^{399} = 2^{399}(2 - 1) = 2^{399}$
I'm guessing the answer will be in the form of an exponent like this

But I do not know how to use the added $2$ in the original equation.

Any help is welcomed, thanks

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, this may be possible to factor. Could it be factored into prime numbers and use the formula $\varphi(p^{k}) = p^{k}-p^{k-1}$ ?

Comment: Hint:  This is equal to $\varphi(2(2^{399} + 1))$.  Hence, the computation will all amount to factoring $2^{399} + 1$, since $\varphi$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Are there any hints you can give me for factoring $2^{399}+1$, I've never done anything like that before

Comment: Additional hint: Since $399 = 3\cdot{133}$, you can factor this as:

$$(2^{133} + 1)(2^{266} - 2^{133} + 1)$$

Comment: As pointed out in a comment on the answer below by @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, this looks like something that couldn't be done by hand.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1022120/determine-phi23991

Comment: someone has downvoted me i'm waiting for another solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

with Maple 18 i got $ \left(  \left( 2 \right)  \right) ^{23} \left(  \left( 3 \right) 
 \right) ^{11} \left(  \left( 5 \right)  \right) ^{2} \left(  \left( 7
 \right)  \right) ^{9} \left( 13 \right)  \left( 17 \right)  \left( 
 \left( 19 \right)  \right) ^{9} \left( 43 \right)  \left( 47 \right) 
 \left( 67 \right)  \left( 73 \right)  \left( 175949 \right)  \left( 
13754192665763002837193 \right)  \left( 209831249 \right)  \left( 
171071713 \right)  \left( 5282364980404051013275727 \right)  \left( 
739601 \right)  \left( 2339 \right) 
$

Comment: Wow. This doesn't look like something that could be done by hand...

Comment: i think also so